# Is it possible to specify specific form fields when initialising a form in a view?

Tags: python, django

I have a form that I'd like to reuse around a site, but there are times where I'd like to omit a specific field from the form. Is it possible to do this when initialising the form in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to delete a field, but You can override the widget of the form in the form's `__init__` method.

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field=forms.CharField()
    other_field=forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, my_criteria, *args,**kwrds):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwrds)
        if my_criteria == 'this':
            self.fields['some_field'].widget = forms.HiddenInput(required=False)
        elif my_criteria == 'that':
             self.fields['other_field'].widget=forms.HiddenInput(required=False)
        #else: pass - leave it the way it is.
```

If you want to render different kinds of forms, you can pass in a parameter with specific values while declaring the form, and use that to render `HiddenInput` widget at runtime that would hide it from the form

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way only for ModelForm but what you can do is this

```
fromd django.forms import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
     text = forms.CharField()
     another_text = forms.CharField()
```

and in your view something like:

```
from myforms import MyForm
from django.shortcuts import render

def view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    model = MyModel()
    model.text = form.clean['text']
    model.another_text = "Some value"
    model.save()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form':form})
```

and in your template.html:

```
<form action="">
    {{form.text}}
</form>
```

this will only display a textfield in your template.html